# Adding threadability to multiple classes/methods

Tags: java

I understand the usefulness of threaded processes for, say, repeatedly running a particular method that needs to be updated regularly. Besides writing specific code in the method class to work in its own thread, is there a way to link a specific method from any (non-threaded) class so that it runs/repeats in its own thread via a separate 'OmniThread' class?

For example, suppose I have a class that has a method that reports the current elapsed time from a value passed as an argument and returns the result as a formatted date String such as "1 hour, 3 mins, 17 secs":

```
public class Timer () {

 public String getTime (long then) {

    now = <some code>;
    duration = then-now;
    <more code>;
    return dateString;
    }
}
```

I want this method to update regularly and also want several other methods from other classes, each with their own function, arguments and return values, to do the same in their own threads.

Is there a way to pass a method with such parameters onto a universal 'OmniThread' class that adds 'threadability' to any method or do I just have to set up each class individually to run in its own thread?

If this is possible how would I pass the values from my method class to the threaded class so it runs as required? How would I end the threads?

In pseudo code I would want to ask the threaded class to run a method I stipulated and update it every half second:

```
OmniThread thread = new OmniThread (<method name>, <method arguments> ,<repeat interval>);
```

It may be that I'm going about this completely the wrong way but would appreciate some input and advice.

Many Thanks,
K

Comment: What are you going to do with the return values?